# Vector Differentiation Derivation for Linear Least Mean Squares Estimators

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, least-squares

*Linear Estimation* by Kailath, Sayed and Hassibi (Section 3.2.1) provides a derivation that the linear least mean squares estimator (LLMSE) $\hat{y}=K_0x$ satisfy the equation $K_0 R_y = R_{xy}$ where $x$ and $y$ are complex vector-valued zero-mean random variables (column vectors), $*$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose, and $R_x=E [xx^*]$ and $R_{xy}=E [xy^*]$ are the covariance matrices.  The proof simply says to differentiate with respect to $aK$ (where $a$ is a row vector):
$$a E[(x-Ky)(x-Ky)^*]a^* = a(R_x - R_{xy} K^* - KR_{yx} + KR_yK^*)a^*$$
and set to zero at $K=K_0$ to arrive at $K_0 R_y = R_{xy}$.

The simplified scalar case is clear. Unfortunatly, I don't know how do this vector differentiation?  For example, what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial (aK)}$ of $aR_{xy}K^*a^*$?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding. There is another book from one of the authors of the book that you have mentioned: A. H. Sayed, Adaptive Filters, Wiley, NJ, 2008. Perhaps it is easier to read than the book you have mentioned. I am sure there are many books/notes for the derivation of LMMSE.

Anyway, the optimization problem for LMMSE weight should read as following
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{K} \operatorname{Tr}(R_x - R_{xy} K^H - KR_{yx} + KR_yK^H),
\end{align}
where $(\cdot)^H$ denotes complex conjugate transpose, whereas $(\cdot)^*$ corresponds to complex conjugate.

To this end, we need to find an optimal weight matrix $K$. We have to use Wirtinger calculus for the gradient computation, i.e., treat $K$ and $K^*$ independently.

Before finding the gradient (and setting it to zero), here are some nomenclature:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm Tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product
  \begin{align}
  A : B C
   &= A^*: B^*C^* \\
   &= BC : A \\
   &= C^TB^T : A^T \\
   &= A C^T   :  B \\
   &= A^T: C^TB^T \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

Let $f := \operatorname{Tr}(R_x - R_{xy} K^H - KR_{yx} + KR_yK^H) \equiv I: \operatorname{Tr}(R_x - R_{xy} K^H - KR_{yx} + KR_yK^H)$.

For simplicity, we will find the differential $dK^*$ (and ignore $dK$).
\begin{align}
df  
&= d\left(I:R_x - R_{xy} K^H - KR_{yx} + KR_yK^H \right) \\
&= \left(I:0 - R_{xy} dK^H - 0 + KR_ydK^H \right) \\
&= \left(I^T: - dK^*R_{xy}^T + dK^* (KR_y)^T \right) \\
&= \left(\left[-R_{xy} + KR_y \right]: dK^*  \right) 
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial K^*} = -R_{xy} + KR_y.
\end{align}

Now, you set the gradient to zero and obtain $K$ (assuming that $R_y$ is invertible and set $K = K_0$):

$$K_0 = R_{xy} R_y^{-1} .$$

Comment: Thank you for your response and thank you for the book suggestion!  I looked and _Adapter Filter_ by Sayed uses the same notation as _Linear Estimation_ (i.e., * for conjugate transpose of a matrix).  I have never seen Wirtinger calculus so I'll have to find some references to learn more.  If we restrict the vectors and matrices to be real valued, does it make things easier?  Could you recommend some good references on Matrix Calculus?  Thank you very much.

Comment: This book can be useful for you: see, e.g., here https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Valued-Matrix-Derivatives-Applications-Communications/dp/0521192641